# Why is there a blank area above my dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my site to be responsive and therefore I want a special menu on small screens. My large screen display is working and my small screen menu is also working but it leaves a blank area at the top of the page and I can't find where it comes from. I just want my whole screen to go black and not have the top area stay on top of the previous one.

Here a screen before press the button :

[image: before]

And here a screen after :

[image: after]

Thx in advance for your help

As shown in the images, my problem is with the area at the top when the menu is activated, as it should be black like the rest, but I don't understand why it remains in its current state.

```js
const hamburger = document.querySelector(".hamburger");
const navLinks = document.querySelector(".nav-links");
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-links li");

hamburger.addEventListener('click', () => {

  navLinks.classList.toggle("open");

  links.forEach(link => {
    link.classList.toggle("fade");
  });

  hamburger.classList.toggle("toggle");

});
```

```css
/*****************************

             Font 

*****************************/

@font-face {
  font-family: 'RomanAntique';
  src: url("../../asset/font/RomanAntique.ttf") format("truetype");
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
}


/*****************************

     Default Background 

*****************************/


/* > 1000px */

body {
  background-image: url("../../asset/img/BackGroundTest.jpg");
  background-size: 100% !important;
}


/* < 1000px */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    background-image: url("../../asset/img/BackGroundTestPhone.jpg") !important;
    background-size: 100% !important;
  }
}


/*****************************

     Default Properties 

*****************************/

body {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'RomanAntique';
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}


/*Styling logo*/

.logo {
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.logo img {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
}


/*Styling Links*/

.nav-links {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  width: 88vw;
  padding: 0 0.7vw;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-links li a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 0 0.7vw;
}

.nav-links li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav-links li a::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  margin: 15% 0 0 10%;
}

.nav-links li a:hover::before {
  width: 80%;
}


/*Styling Hamburger Icon*/

.hamburger div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 3px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.hamburger {
  display: none;
}


/*Stying for small screens*/

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  nav {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  .hamburger {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    right: 5%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-5%, -50%);
    z-index: 999999;
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
  }
  .nav-links {
    position: fixed;
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -20%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(50px at 90% -10%);
    transition: all 1s ease-out;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
  .nav-links.open {
    clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -10%);
    -webkit-clip-path: circle(1500px at 100% -10%);
    pointer-events: all;
  }
  .nav-links li {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(1) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.2s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(2) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.4s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(3) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.6s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(4) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 0.8s;
  }
  .nav-links li:nth-child(5) {
    transition: all 0.5s ease 1.0s;
  }
  li.fade {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


/*Animating Hamburger Icon on Click*/

.toggle .line1 {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
  width: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="Logo Image">
  </div>

  <div class="hamburger">
    <div class="line1"></div>
    <div class="line2"></div>
    <div class="line3"></div>
  </div>

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li><a href="">Nos Produits</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Notre Histoire</a></li>
    <li><a href="">&nbsp; &nbsp; Galerie &nbsp; &nbsp;</a></li>
    <li><a href="">&nbsp; &nbsp; Salons &nbsp; &nbsp; </a></li>
    <li><a href="">&nbsp; &nbsp; Contact &nbsp; &nbsp; </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<!-- <script src="../../asset/js/Menubtn.js"></script> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your menu is showing white space at the top is because you didn't set your menu's margin to 0. `<ul>` items by default have a margin on the top. If you change your `.nav-links` selector code to look like this it should work:

```
.nav-links {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    width: 88vw;
    padding: 0 0.7vw;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thx you very much it's working, i was not aware of the default margin.

Answer (score 0):

I inspected your code in the dev console and found that the top margin you are seeing from the `<ul>` element. 16px to be exact. To resolve your issue, you'll need to update the your styling on .nav-links. One possible solution is adding `margin-top:0px`.

Comment: Yes, i was not aware of the default pading of the element i have add it and it's working now thx you